# Understanding type casting in c

Tags: c

I'm following a book on c, and I come to some code that reads a file with 3 lines of text.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE    *fp;
    int c;

    fp = fopen( "../../My Data File", "r" );

    if ( NULL == fp ) {
        printf( "Error opening ../My Data File" );
    } else {
        while ( (c = fgetc( fp )) != EOF )
            putchar ( c );

        fclose( fp );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to modify it, to detect each line and print the current line number by making these modifications.

```
int line = 1;

while ( (c = fgetc( fp )) != EOF ){
    if (c == '\n'){
        printf(" LINE %d", line);
        putchar( c );
        line++;
    }
    else {
        putchar ( c );
    }
}
```

But it failed to print the line #, till I changed the type of the variable c to a char. Is there a way to check for a newline while still using c as an int?

What is the proper way to check for a newline?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? because it is working fine with me. I think you need to clarify more what you want to do.

Comment: That should have worked. '\n' is automatically promoted to an int if you compare it with one.

Comment: You are saying that the first program worked and making the changes you've shown in the second snipped "didn't work"?  You should post the complete program and also tell us what didn't work.

Comment: @Daniel:  In C, character literals have type `int`, so `\n` is an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code prints line numbers at the end of a line, right before printing the `'\n'`, because of the way you have written the loop.  Otherwise, your code should work.

If you want your code to print the line numbers at the beginning, you can do something like (untested):

```
int line_num_printed = 0; /* indicating if we printed a line number */
int line = 1;

while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (!line_num_printed) {
        printf("LINE %d: ", line);
        line_num_printed = 1;
    }
    putchar(c);
    if (c == '\n'){
        line++;
        line_num_printed = 0;
    }
}
```

If there is something else that "doesn't work", you should post complete code and tell us what doesn't work.

*Edit*: The proper way to check a character for a newline is to test against `'\n'`.  If the character came from a file, you should also make sure you open the file in text mode, i.e., without a `b` in the second argument to `fopen()`.

Also, you want `c` to be of type `int`, not `char`.  This is because in C, `EOF` is a small negative number, and if `char` is unsigned, comparing it against a negative number convert the value of `EOF` to a positive value (equal to `EOF + UCHAR_MAX + 1` most likely).  Therefore, you should *not* change `c` to `char` type.  If you do, the comparison `c != EOF` might be false even when `fgetc()` returns `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the integer code for a new line ('\n') is 13. So you could do ( if (c == 13) ), but also note that windows files use 2 characters to define a new line '\r' and '\n'.  The integer character for '\r' is 10.  But basically yes you can keep 'c' as an int and just compare against 13.

Comment: In addition to everything Alok already said, "usually" is a poor way to explain the line-ending problem to someone. It can be described exactly: Windows uses `\r\n`, Mac OS Classic used `\r`, and Unix-based systems (Linux, Mac OS X, *BSD, etc.) and many others use `\n`. Saying "usually" makes it sound more mysterious and magical.

Comment: And since the file was not opened in binary mode, stdio will convert CR-LF (i.e. `\r\n`) to LF ('\n')

Comment: @Chris: "described EXACTLY"? No, I don't think so. ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_line

Comment: @ferrari fan: I think you've swapped the two. Line feed ('\n') is 10, carriage return ('\r') is 13. See any ASCII table (such as http://www.asciitable.com/).